# Does ndb.delete_multi with all keys from the same parent count as a single update to the entity group?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm deciding whether or not to include a "fetch 200/delete 200" routine of a pipeline inside a transaction.

If not included and the request/instance dies abruptly, the fetched entities would be lost.

Since with xg=True, the entity group limit is 5, the 200 entities need to have the same parent to be included in the transaction.

If delete_multi with 200 keys, count as 200 simultaneous updates to the entity group, the routine might fail, as the preferred limit to entity groups is 1/second.

When those 200 entities are deleted with ndb.delete_multi, does it count as 1 updates or 200 updates to the entity group?

Comment: I don't know offhand, but I'd look at appstats first to find out. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Comment: I don't know how appstats data could have interpreted for this scenario, it's also extremely buggy lately, loading 1000 items with a long load time and refreshing buggily forever, but thanks for the suggestion anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the same transaction you can delete 200 entities/keys in one go.

The 1/second limit (more likely 5/second) should be read as: How often can I start (and commit) an *independent* transaction on an entity group or x-group. T.i. because each transaction needs a lock on the root element you're commiting.